# Duplicate entries inside array of objects: Javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, setstate, react-table

I am trying to add entries into an array, the entries being an object that corresponds to the row of a table. Each row is being highlighted by a color once it is selected. Multiple rows can also be selected using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> Key.  On each click I am pushing that row info object into the array. It is defined as a SET and same entry is being duplicated when the same row is clicked multiple times. Also I am unable to de-select the one's that are selected.I am  using react-table for the data-grid purposes. Can some one help me out here? Help would be really appreciated.

Sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-table-row-table-final-hor8j

```js
import * as React from "react";
import ReactTable from "react-table";

export default class DataGrid extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      selectedRows: []
    };
  }

  rowClick = (state, rowInfo) => {
    if (rowInfo) {
      let selectedRows = new Set();
      return {
        onClick: e => {
          if (e.ctrlKey) {
            selectedRows = this.state.selectedRows;
            rowInfo._index = rowInfo.index;
            selectedRows.push(rowInfo);
            this.setState({
              selectedRows
            });
          } else {
            selectedRows = [];
            rowInfo._index = rowInfo.index;
            selectedRows.push(rowInfo);
          }
          this.setState(
            {
              selectedRows
            },
            () => {
              console.log("final values", this.state.selectedRows);
              this.props.rowClicked(this.state.selectedRows);
            }
          );
        },
        style: {
          background:
            this.state.selectedRows.some(e => e._index === rowInfo.index) &&
            "#9bdfff"
        }
      };
    } else {
      return "";
    }
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <ReactTable
        data={this.props.data}
        columns={this.props.columns}
        getTrProps={this.rowClick}
      />
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: `Even though its defined as a SET, still it has duplicates when the same row is clicked multiple times` This happens because even if the object might have the same properties, it's different reference to an object. If you do `new Set([{}, {}])` you will see that it have size of 2.

Comment: You define selectedRows here: ` let selectedRows = new Set();` -- but you replace the value of selectedRows every time before you use it, `selectedRows = this.state.selectedRows;` besides, a Set doesn't have a `push` function

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Remove duplicates from an array of objects in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2218999/remove-duplicates-from-an-array-of-objects-in-javascript)

Comment: I added a solution using a `Set` (which is a great idea) and allows you to select and unselect multiple rows.

Comment: @Brett DeWoody wanted something in terms of react table. Like the one in the sandbox. Thanks anyways :)

Comment: Ah, got it, I thought the question was more around how to use `Set`.

Comment: @Brett DeWoody. You could still give a simplified solution if you've got one, by modifying the same sandbox :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an updated sandbox to avoid duplicates https://codesandbox.io/s/react-table-row-table-alternate-single-row-working-1itsy

The solution includes unselecting rows on second click.

Happy coding:)

Comment: I have posted a solution. Let me know if that is what you wanted.

Answer (score 2):

You have defined selectedRows as an empty Set but then quickly replaced it with an array `this.state.selectedRows`. Every operation done post this would be done on the array instead of the set.

Here is an example of how you can make changes to your code to use a set instead:

```js
const selectedRows = new Set(this.state.selectedRows); // Initialise the set with the items from your array. 
...
selectedRows.add(rowInfo); // Similar to an array push
```

You can find more on how the JS Set works at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simplified demo using a functional component and `Set` to manage the selected rows. It allows rows to be selected and unselected.

This functional component could be changed to extend `React.Component` using a similar setup.

```js
const App = ({data}) => {

  const [selected, setSelected] = React.useState(new Set());

  const handleClick = (row) => {
    const updatedSelected = new Set(selected);
    
    if (updatedSelected.has(row)) {
      updatedSelected.delete(row);
    } else {
      updatedSelected.add(row);
    }
    
    setSelected(updatedSelected);
  }
  
  React.useEffect(() => {
    console.log(Array.from(selected));
  });

  return (
    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>ID</th>
          <th>Name</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
      {data.map(row => (
        <tr onClick={() => handleClick(row)} className={selected.has(row) && 'selected'}>
          <td>{row.id}</td>
          <td>{row.text}</td>
        </tr>
      ))}
      </tbody>
    </table>
  )
}

const data = [
  {id: 0, text: 0},
  {id: 1, text: 1},
  {id: 2, text: 2},
  {id: 3, text: 3},
  {id: 4, text: 4},
  {id: 5, text: 5},
  {id: 6, text: 6},
  {id: 7, text: 7},
  {id: 8, text: 8}
]


ReactDOM.render(<App data={data} />, document.getElementById('root'))
```

```css
.selected {
  background-color: lightgreen;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.11.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.11.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```